# LARAVEL - Not able to call a function inside a controller method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here is comment method of CommentController

```
public function comment(Request $request)
{

    $comments = DB::table('comments')
                    ->join('answers', 'answers.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                    ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                    ->where('answers.id', '=' , '9')
                    ->where('parent_id', '0')
                    ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                             'comments.id as comment_id',
                             'comments.created_at as created_at',
                             'comments.parent_id as parent_id',
                             // 'answers.aanswer as answer',
                             'answers.id as ans_id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();


    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
         echo $comment->comment_id.$comment->comment.'<br>';
        return $this->testingComment();
    }


    public function testingComment(){
        echo "testing comments function";
    }

}
```

**I have this foreach loop  , I am just t trying to call this testingComment function in loop, but its not working.**

I am building a nested comment system and i want to call function inside foreach loop to render child and sub child comments when a  when a parent_id matches

Comment: Isnt that `testingComment` declared inside `comment` function? That code is barely readable.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the error it returns?

Comment: Given the pattern of your code, it's obvious that you've declared the function inside of your `comment()` function. Move it outside of it.

Comment: I am fetching it using ajax so i am getting this - POST http://localhost:8000/comm 500 (Internal Server Error) ... Can't just i call a any simple  function inside a foreach loop?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks, It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please copy and paste the below code it will works fine and you missed some `}`:

```
public function comment(Request $request)
{

      $comments = DB::table('comments')
                        ->join('answers', 'answers.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                        ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                        ->where('answers.id', '=' , '9')
                        ->where('parent_id', '0')
                        ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                                'comments.id as comment_id',
                                'comments.created_at as created_at',
                                'comments.parent_id as parent_id',
                                // 'answers.aanswer as answer',
                                'answers.id as ans_id')

                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();


       foreach ($comments as $comment) {
          echo $comment->comment_id.$comment->comment.'<br>';
          return $this->testingComment();
       }

}

public function testingComment(){
                echo "testing comments function";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are defining function inside function, try below code

public function comment(Request $request) {

```
    $comments = DB::table('comments')
            ->join('answers', 'answers.id', '=', 'comments.answer_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'comments.user_id')
            ->where('answers.id', '=', '9')
            ->where('parent_id', '0')
            ->select('comments.comment as comment', 'comments.id as comment_id', 'comments.created_at as created_at', 'comments.parent_id as parent_id',
                    // 'answers.aanswer as answer',
                    'answers.id as ans_id')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();


    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        echo $comment->comment_id . $comment->comment . '<br>';
        return $this->testingComment();
    }
}

public function testingComment() {
    echo "testing comments function";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're other function is inside the comment function, which is most likely the reason why it's not doing anything or breaking.

```
public function comment(Request $request)
{
    $comments = DB::table('comments')
                    ->join('answers', 'answers.id' , '=', 'comments.answer_id')
                    ->join('users' , 'users.id' , '=', 'comments.user_id')
                    ->where('answers.id', '=' , '9')
                    ->where('parent_id', '0')
                    ->select('comments.comment as comment',
                             'comments.id as comment_id',
                             'comments.created_at as created_at',
                             'comments.parent_id as parent_id',
                             // 'answers.aanswer as answer',
                             'answers.id as ans_id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();


    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
         echo $comment->comment_id.$comment->comment.'<br>';
        return $this->testingComment();
    }
}

public function testingComment()
{
    echo "testing comments function";
}
```